# Infix to Prefix conversion, segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a given infix expression to prefix. But I get a segmentation fault, core dumped error.Has it got something to do with using "gets" (I get the warning that it is dangerous to use) or the lot of if statements in precedence and isOperator fucntion? I think my logic is correct, so Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in adance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 50
char stack[MAX];
int top=-1;
void reverse(char array[MAX]){
    int i,j;
    char temp[MAX];
    for(i=strlen(array)-1,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++){
        temp[j]=array[i];
    }
    temp[j]='/0';
    strcpy(array,temp);
}
char pop(){
    return stack[top--];
}
void push(char ele){
    stack[++top]=ele;
}
int isOperator(char ele){
    if(ele=="+"||ele=="-"||ele=="*"||ele=="^"||ele=="/"||ele=="#"||ele=="("||ele==")"){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
int precedence(char ele){
    if(ele=="+"||ele=="-"){
        return 2;
    }
    if(ele=="("||ele=="("||ele=="#"){
        return 1;
    }
    if(ele=="*"){
        return 3;
    }
    if(ele=="/"){
        return 4;
    }
    if(ele=="^"){
        return 5;
    }
}
void infixToPrefix(char infix[MAX],char prefix[MAX]){
    int i,j=0;
    reverse(infix);
    char symbol;
    stack[++top]="#";
    for(i=0;i<strlen(infix);i++){
        symbol=infix[i];
        if(isOperator(symbol)==0){
            prefix[j]=symbol;
            j++;
        }
        else{
            if(symbol==")"){
                push(symbol);
            }
            else if(symbol=="("){
                while(stack[top]!=")"){
                    prefix[j]=pop();
                    j++;
                }
                pop();//to remove the bracket 
            }
            else{
                if(precedence(symbol)<=precedence(stack[top])){
                    push(symbol);
                }
                else{
                    while(precedence(symbol)>=precedence(stack[top])){
                        prefix[j]=pop();
                        j++;
                    }
                    push(symbol);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while(stack[top]!="#"){
        prefix[j]=pop();
        j++;
    }
    prefix[j]="\0";
}
int main(){
    char infix[MAX],prefix[MAX];
    gets(infix);
    infixToPrefix(infix,prefix);
    reverse(prefix);
    puts(prefix);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: all `ele=="+"` s are wrong, you need to use `''`s.

Comment: use a debugger and step through it until it crashes.

Comment: `'/0'` --> `'\0'` or `0`

Comment: I applied both the suggested changes, I still get the segmentation fault error.

Comment: Overkill the `pop`.

Comment: umm, I am sorry, I don't understand. I am new to programming, what does Overkill the pop mean?

Comment: e.g. input `a+b` ==> push(#) ==> b add prefix ==> symbol(+) >= stack top(#)  ==> pop # (stack empty) ==> symbol(+) > stack underflow ...and so on.

Comment: Also `ele=="("||ele=="("` duplicate. typo ?

Comment: I suggest for each of your while loops, you print out the value of j. You will quickly see it reaching values far far greater than your stack for many inputs such as "A(B*C)+D". The stack eventually corrupts the actual programs stack and causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes, I now realise it. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: OH! I realise my mistake! its in the If else statement. it should have been predence(stack[top])<precedence(symbol) and I wrote it reverse.